# How to retrieve genre from JSON result

Tags: android, json

I can not retrieve all key values from JSON object retrieved from HTTP request.

This is the returned JSON object from http request:

```
 {"data":[{"movie_id":3,"movie_name":"Promithius","genre":"a dude","year":"2016","rating":45}]}
```

my Android Code:

```
 try {
                //HttpJsonParser httpJsonParser = new HttpJsonParser();
                JSONObject JSonObj = (JSONObject)  new 
 JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
                String mymovie = JSonObj.getString("movie_name" );
                String movieGenre = JSonObj.getString("genre" );
                etResponse.setText("movie=" + mymovie + " genre=" + 
 movieGenre);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                etResponse.setText("ERROR=" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I run it in emulator with only:

```
 String mymovie = JSonObj.getString("movie_name" );
 etResponse.setText("movie=" + mymovie;
```

I get back the Movie name with no error. So the issue is I can retrieve movie_name but no Genre.
Error returned says "No value for genre"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that you have typed genre right ?

Comment: Maybe some records have no genre data, but likely all have the movie_name?

Comment: You might want to look at using Retrofit + Gson for mapping HTTP JSON results to full objects

Answer (score 0):

I think the data is JSONArray.

```
String result = "{\"data\":[{\"movie_id\":3,\"movie_name\":\"Promithius\",\"genre\":\"a dude\",\"year\":\"2016\",\"rating\":45}]}";

        try {
            JSONObject JSonObj = (JSONObject)  new JSONTokener(result).nextValue();
            JSONArray data = JSonObj.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i=0; i<data.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
                String mymovie = jsonObject.getString("movie_name" );
                String movieGenre = jsonObject.getString("genre" );
                String dest = "movie=" + mymovie + " genre=" + movieGenre;
                Log.d(TAG, dest);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that finally worked for me. I hope it can help someone else.

```
 try{
 JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
 JSONArray Jarray  = object.getJSONArray("data");
 object = Jarray.getJSONObject(0);
 String MovieName = object.getString("movie_name");
 String Genre = object.getString("genre");
 String Rating = object.getString("rating");
 String Year = object.getString("year");
 etResponse.setText("Movie Name = " + MovieName + " \n Genre = " + 
 Genre + "\n Rating = " + Rating + " \n Year = " + Year );
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    etResponse.setText("JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```